# Conditionally Add Cell Data to NSMutable Array

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Having a lot of trouble with this today. Finally decided to turn to the experts.

I have a standard Table View Controller. Each cell has a built-in UIImage with a tap gesture recognizer that toggles the image back and forth from a green checkmark to a red x. That's working just fine.

What I'm trying to do now is write a conditional statement that says: When the image is a green checkmark, add the cell textLabel to the `saved` NSMutableArray; else remove red x objects from the array (that may have been added at an earlier time). Currently I'm getting "null" in the console on both accounts.

Here's the original method:

```
-(void)imageTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{

    UIImageView *selectedImageView=(UIImageView*)[gesture view];
    UIImage *imageRed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkmark(red).png"];
    UIImage *imageGreen = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkmark(green).png"];

    NSString *address = @" ";
    NSString *name = @" ";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.placesTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.placesTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow];
    name = cell.textLabel.text;
    address = cell.detailTextLabel.text;
    NSMutableArray *saved = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"%@",@"%@", name, address, nil];
    NSString *csv = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", name, address];

    if (selectedImageView.image == imageGreen) {
        selectedImageView.image = imageRed;
        [saved removeObject:csv];
        NSLog(@"Deselected" @"%@", name);
    } else {
        selectedImageView.image = imageGreen;
        [saved addObject:csv];
        NSLog(@"Selected" @"%@", name);
    }
}
```

EDITED: Suggested method (still not working):

h: `@property (strong, nonatomic)          NSMutableArray *saved;`

m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _saved = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

    -(void)imageTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{

    UIImageView *selectedImageView=(UIImageView*)[gesture view];
    UIImage *imageRed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkmark(red).png"];
    UIImage *imageGreen = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkmark(green).png"];
    NSString *address = @" ";
    NSString *name = @" ";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.placesTableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.placesTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow];
    name = cell.textLabel.text;
    address = cell.detailTextLabel.text;
    NSString *csv = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", name, address];
    self.saved = [NSMutableArray array];

    //NSData *imageRedData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageRed);
    NSData *imageGreenData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageGreen);
    NSData *selectedImageViewData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(selectedImageView.image);

    if ( [selectedImageViewData isEqual: imageGreenData]) {
        selectedImageView.image = imageRed;
        [self.saved removeObject:csv];
        NSLog(@"Deselected" @"%@", name);
    } else {
        selectedImageView.image = imageGreen;
        [self.saved addObject:csv];
        NSLog(@"Selected" @"%@", name);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is nil? the `name` pointer in the NSLog statements, or is `self.saved` nil when you try to remove/add objects to it?

Comment: if `_saved` is not nil, its likely that your `cell` is. Double check the value that's coming from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Both seem to be. I'm getting "Selected(null)" in the log (when I call `name`), but also when I call `_saved`. I'm passing the `cell.textLabel.text` in another method, so I'm know I'm getting data.

Comment: Have you debugged into the line `name = cell.textLabel.text` and verified in that case that cell is not nil?

Comment: Also, your log statements look weird. Are you sure they're doing what you think they're doing? Try changing the first one to `NSLog(@"Deselected %@", name);`

Comment: Ah, another problem here. You're resetting `_saved` to an empty array whenever you tap the image. Remove the line `self.saved = [NSMutableArray array];`

Comment: Ok, I removed that line and also debugged the method. You were right, the (current) problem seems to be in the three lines referring to  `cell`, `name`, and `address`. Not sure where to go from here, but at least I know where the root of the issue is.

Comment: 1. `cell` might be nil. Write `NSLog(@"%@", cell);` after you get it from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, to verify.

Comment: 2. If it is, your problem might be that the `indexPathForSelectedRow` is nil, probably meaning you don't actually have a row selected.

Comment: 1. Yep, `cell` is nil. Guess I'll start there. As for 2., adding `cell.selected = true;` before adding the object should do the trick, right?

Comment: It's doubtful. You need to determine why cell is nil. Typically cellForRowAtIndexPath doesn't return a nil cell. You probably need to get the cell your image is in, rather than the one that is selected. Perhaps using the view hierarchy.

Comment: Also, Obj-C uses YES/NO for boolean values.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to create the saved mutable array every time?  It won't persist past the end of the imageTapped method.  Perhaps you want this NSMutableArray to be a property (or ivar) and add-to or remove from self.saved?

Comment: Excellent point. So I've moved the initialization to the viewDidLoad method, added the property, and changed saved to self.saved, but still getting null (added edited code above). Even implemented @Rocker's changes since it seemed to make some logical sense, but that didn't work either. Anything else jump at you? THANKS!

Comment: Hmmm....  Well my advice at this point is to set a breakpoint at the beginning of imageTapped, step through the method line by line and make sure that the variable values are what you expect at every point.  -- for instance that the imageNamed method actually returns non-nil values and such.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the UIImage comparison logic, instead of using = operator use isEqual method on NSObject. Here is a solution code which help you.

```
 -(void)imageTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gesture
 {

     UIImageView *selectedImageView=(UIImageView*)[gesture view];
     UIImage *imageRed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkmark(red).png"];
     UIImage *imageGreen = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkmark(green).png"];
     NSString *address = @" ";
     NSString *name = @" ";
     UITableViewCell *cell = [self.placesTableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.placesTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow];
     name = cell.textLabel.text;
     address = cell.detailTextLabel.text;
     NSMutableArray *saved = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"%@",@"%@", name, address, nil];
     NSString *csv = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", name, address];

    NSData *imageRedData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageRed);
    NSData *imageGreenData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageGreen);
    NSData *selectedImageViewData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(selectedImageView.image);  

    if ( [selectedImageViewData isEqual: imageGreenData]) {
         selectedImageView.image = imageRed;
        [saved removeObject:csv];
        NSLog(@"Deselected" @"%@", name);
    } else {
        selectedImageView.image = imageGreen;
        [saved addObject:csv];
        NSLog(@"Selected" @"%@", name);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that didn't do the trick, although it makes sense to me. Anything else jump at you? I've added edited code after seeing @Charlie Price's answer below. Thanks!